# Can I format ISO date in Excel using custom formatting?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have data coming from external source. Some of the columns look like `2019-01-27T00:00:00Z` (time is always 0). I want to show it as `January 27, 2019`. It looks like date formatting doesn't work. Obviously, I can copy to another column as `=DATEVALUE(LEFT(C2,10))` and format there. But I would much prefer to format in place using custom formatting. Is it possible?

UPDATE: I am getting answers and comments that I am not sure how they are relevant to my question. So let me rephrase my question succinctly: Is it possible to use custom formatting, so that the value of `2019-01-27T00:00:00Z` will be displayed as `January 27, 2019`?

Comment: Are the dates in your data stored as text or Excel date/times?  If they're stored as numerical values, just apply the formatting you want.  If it's text, you can't change the format in place because they are literal characters and there is no way to change their appearance without changing the content.

Comment: it's text (it comes as CSV file). When I save it as Excel it stays as string. But literal characters of, say, `2019-01-27` can be formatted to appear as date just fine. Or I misunderstood your question?

Comment: If Excel recognizes the CSV data as potentially a legitimate date, it can treat it as numerical data if you try to use it that way.  But if it doesn't recognize it as potentially a date, it will treat it only as text.  Your settings such as locale affect how it tries to interpret the string.  So you can get strange stuff like some countries using DDMMYYY and others using MMDDYYYY, and dates for which the digits could be legit in either format will be treated as numbers (though not necessarily correctly), but digits that can't be legit in the other format get treated as text.

Comment: not sure how it relates to my question... the whole point of ISO format is to avoid locale dependency. In any event, it *started* as CSV file, but I saved as XLSX. And if the time portion (`T00Z`) is omitted, I can manipulate it through date formatting just fine

Comment: You can try simply formatting the cell to see if it works.  If your Excel implementation can see the values reliably as potential date/times and interpret the values correctly, it may work.  However, you can't change text content via formatting.  So if your Excel sees it as text, you cannot do what you want in the original cell.  That's what I tried to explain previously.

Comment: ok, I give up... obviously, developers and super users think differently. Where on earth did I say that I want to change text via formatting. And obviously, I tried different date formats - as I mentioned, it works, if the value doesn't have time portion. Thank you everybody for trying to help...

Comment: You keep ignoring the answer to what you're asking.  You have date/times stored as text.  You think you ought to be able to simply apply formatting to the cell and change the appearance to a date in a different format.  If you chop off the time, you can do that.  If you don't chop off the time, it doesn't work.  You've already demonstrated the answer for yourself.  You cannot simply apply formatting as-is.  You need to modify the content, and there are different ways you can do that.  All the rest is just explanation, which you don't think is relevant.

Comment: it doesn't work with *date format*. There are more than a dozen of **custom formats** that I am not familiar with. I played a little with what seemed intuitive, and googled a little - but couldn't find anything relevant. I was hoping that some better excel experts will guide me to some **custom format** that would be a starting point in the right direction. If there is no such format - ok, it's a good answer as well.

Comment: You ask “Where on earth did I say that I want to change text via formatting.” in a comment.  (Well, I guess it’s a question, although you didn’t end it with a question mark.)  And you said in your question (post) “Is it possible to use custom formatting, so that the value of `2019-01-27T00:00:00Z` will be displayed as `January 27, 2019`?” ***That*** is where you said that you want to change text via formatting. … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … I agree with @fixer1234: you can’t do what you want without using a secondary cell (“helper column”).

Comment: Custom formats won't be any different.  You can't do what you're trying to do if Excel sees the cell content as text, which is why it doesn't work with date formatting when you don't chop off the time.

Answer (score 1):

If your "=DATEVALUE(LEFT(C2,10))" works, then just encapsulate it with the TEXT function:

```
=TEXT(DATEVALUE(LEFT(C2,10)), "MMMM DD, YYYY")
```

Comment: Obviously, I was not successful in asking the question... let me rephrase it

Comment: @felix so it seems you wish to format it _upon import_?  How/what are you using to collect your data into Excel?

Comment: No!!! I want to change how it is displayed without changing the data. For example, if it is `2019-01-27`, I go to Format Cells... choose Date, and choose whatever I want. If it is impossible - that's fine, but I thought it would be a very straightforward question :(